# R, problems plotting dates in Shiny and ggvis

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis, posixct

I'm a bit new to Shiny and ggvis, and actually have a couple of problems here.  First I have data in the format:

```
            Event.Hour Count    Group
1  2015-10-08 00:00:00  1476      All
2  2015-10-08 01:00:00 22186      All
3  2015-10-08 02:00:00  2958      All
4  2015-10-08 03:00:00  3484      All
5  2015-10-08 04:00:00  4159      All
6  2015-10-08 05:00:00  2960      All
7  2015-10-08 00:00:00   222 Business
8  2015-10-08 01:00:00    26 Business
9  2015-10-08 02:00:00   542 Business
10 2015-10-08 03:00:00    26 Business
11 2015-10-08 04:00:00  4760 Business
12 2015-10-08 05:00:00  4640 Business
13 2015-10-08 00:00:00  1704   System
14 2015-10-08 01:00:00   100   System
15 2015-10-08 02:00:00   122   System
16 2015-10-08 03:00:00    10   System
17 2015-10-08 04:00:00  3339   System
18 2015-10-08 05:00:00  5370   System
```

The dates were created using lubridate's dmy_hms function:

```
> class(viz_set$Event.Hour)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Code to recreate data set:

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

zz<- "Event.Hour Count    Group
1  2015-10-08-00:00:00  1476      All
2  2015-10-08-01:00:00 22186      All
3  2015-10-08-02:00:00  2958      All
4  2015-10-08-03:00:00  3484      All
5  2015-10-08-04:00:00  4159      All
6  2015-10-08-05:00:00  2960      All
7  2015-10-08-00:00:00   222 Business
8  2015-10-08-01:00:00    26 Business
9  2015-10-08-02:00:00   542 Business
10 2015-10-08-03:00:00    26 Business
11 2015-10-08-04:00:00  4760 Business  
12 2015-10-08-05:00:00  4640 Business
13 2015-10-08-00:00:00  1704   System
14 2015-10-08-01:00:00   100   System
15 2015-10-08-02:00:00   122   System
16 2015-10-08-03:00:00    10   System
17 2015-10-08-04:00:00  3339   System
18 2015-10-08-05:00:00  5370   System"

viz_set<-read.table(text=zz, header = T)

viz_set$Event.Hour <- ymd_hms(viz_set$Event.Hour)
```

I am then plotting the data as a ggvis object and adding a tooltip to the interactive visual:

```
getData1 <- function(dat){
  paste(paste("Value:", dat$Count, "<br />"),
        paste("Time:", dat$Event.Hour))
} 

viz_set %>%
  ggvis(~Event.Hour, ~Count, stroke = ~Group) %>% 
  filter(Group %in% eval(input_checkboxgroup(c("All", "Business", "System"), select = "All"))) %>%
  layer_lines(strokeWidth := 2) %>%
  scale_datetime(property = "x", nice = "hour") %>%
  layer_points(opacity = 0, fill = ~Group) %>%
  add_tooltip(getData1, on = "click") %>%
  add_axis("x", subdivide = 5, tick_size_major=10, tick_size_minor = 5, title = "Event.Hour", title_offset = 30) %>%
  add_axis("y", title = "Count", title_offset = 60)
```

The resulting tooltip displays the dates in Unix epoch format, and I cannot figure out how to get it to simply display as a character.

Inside the getData1 function I've tried:

```
as.character(dat$Event.Hour)
```

and

```
as.POSIXct(dat$Event.Hour, origin = '1970-01-01')
```

to no avail.

I've also tried adding a new column with the dates as character strings, and used the tooltip on that column instead.  Neither have worked.

Second, in the resulting ggvis plot, the X-axis datetimes do not line up with the values.  The data appears to start and end several hours before it should:

[Here you can see that the X-axis is off by a few hours.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKXWk.png)

The first data point should start right at the The Oct 08 line, and it should end at 2 pm on the Wed 14.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and you'll be more likely to get help

Comment: Could you give your example data via `dput` so it's easy to read in?  The above comment link shows a nice example.  You may be able to work around the first problem using a `key` in your points layer and creating your tooltip function a la the last example in the `add_tooltip` help page.  Then you can use that character version of the date-time variable you put in your dataset.

Comment: Here is an [open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/285) on the *ggvis* github repository that looks relevant to your tooltip/datetime problem.

Comment: @alexwhan Thanks Alex! I added some code to recreate the dataset, so everything should be easily reproducible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the time zone may be causing the shifted axis. One simple fix is to simply set the time zone in `ymd_dms` to your system's time zone.  Things for me looked reasonable after that.

```
(mytz = Sys.timezone())
[1] "America/Los_Angeles"

viz_set$Event.Hour = ymd_hms(viz_set$Event.Hour, tz = mytz)
```

In terms of the tooltip, a work around for the time in milliseconds problem would be to simply show the data from the original dataset rather than the dataset coming through `ggvis`.  You can do this by using a `key`.  This involves making an id variable that uniquely represents each row in the original dataset.

```
viz_set$id = 1:nrow(viz_set)
```

Now the tooltip function can look something like the following.

```
getData2 = function(dat){
    if(is.null(dat$id)) return(NULL)
    row = viz_set[viz_set$id == dat$id, ]
    paste(paste("Value:", row$Count, "<br />"),
         paste("Time:", as.character(row$Event.Hour)))
}
```

Notice that, unlike the help documentation, the first row of the function involves `dat$id` and not just `dat`.  When I used `dat` here, I would sometimes get blank tooltip info showing up if I mistakenly clicked on the line instead of the point.  My alternative seems to solve that problem.

Now just add `key := ~id` to `layer_points` to get the tooltip values popping up from the actual dataset.

```
viz_set %>%
    ggvis(~Event.Hour, ~Count, stroke = ~Group) %>% 
    filter(Group %in% eval(input_checkboxgroup(c("All", "Business", "System"), select = "All"))) %>%
    layer_lines(strokeWidth := 2) %>%
    scale_datetime(property = "x", nice = "hour") %>%
    layer_points(opacity := 0, fill = ~Group, key := ~id) %>%
    add_tooltip(getData2, on = "click") %>%
    add_axis("x", subdivide = 5, tick_size_major=10, tick_size_minor = 5, title = "Event.Hour", title_offset = 30) %>%
    add_axis("y", title = "Count", title_offset = 60)
```